# utf8_encode not encoding/converting character

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm trying to use utf8_encode to display some accented characters (for purposes of putting them into a json), but for some reason it seems to fail and I don't understand why. Here's the test data I was running through a php tester:

```
    $data = '{"14446":"discreci\u00f3n","14450":"prudencia","14461":"experiencia","14491":"vida"}';
    $data = preg_replace('|u00([A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9])|', 'x{$1}', $data);
    echo $data;
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    $data = preg_replace('/"\d*":/','',$data); 
    echo $data;
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    $data = preg_replace('/[{}"?!]/','',$data);
    echo $data;
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    $data_array = explode(",", $data); 
        
        foreach ($data_array as $data) {
            echo $data;
            echo "\r\n\r\n";
        }
        
    echo utf8_encode($data_array[0]);

    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    echo utf8_encode("discreci\xf3n");
```

Which output:

> {"14446":"discreci\x{f3}n","14450":"prudencia","14461":"experiencia","14491":"vida"}

> {"discreci\x{f3}n","prudencia","experiencia","vida"}

> discreci\xf3n,prudencia,experiencia,vida

> discreci\xf3n

> prudencia

> experiencia

> vida

> discreci\xf3n

> discreción

As you can see, it converts it if I enter it directly, but it doesn't convert it if it receives it as a variable, even if it's been surrounded with quotation marks eg.:

```
foreach ($data_array as $data) {
                $data = '"' . $data . '"';
                echo $data;
                echo "\r\n\r\n";
            }
```

doesn't convert it either.

So - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The original string appears to be valid JSON already: https://3v4l.org/DomZc. I'm not clear why you need RegEx?

Comment: Doing a simple `json_decode($data)` will show the accented character. JSON supports `\u00f3` syntax so if you were to convert it into an accented character using regex, then `json_encode`, it will turn it back into `\u00f3`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, the number strings are irrelevant and there's other data I need to manipulate with it

Comment: @user8539669, I'm still unclear as to your problem. In almost every case on this site when someone is doing something with the text-encoding functions, they are doing something the hard and usually wrong way. I'm **not** saying _you_ are doing it wrong, to be clear, this is just my first intuition because I don't fully understand the problem. You've posted your sample input, can you post what you expect for sample output to help us better understand?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Jasen's suggestion below sorted it out, but I ultimately need to make a list of word pairs ([[fuerza, vida], [fuerza, discreción], [fuerza, prudencia]]) that I can pop into a different program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create a string that contains `\xf3` these are all ASCII characters.
if you want `ó` you can use stripcslashes to activate the embedded `\`

```
 echo utf8_encode(stripcslashes($data_array[0]));
```

But on the other hand

```
foreach( json_decode($data,1) as $v )  echo $v ,"\n\n" ;
```

Works just fine on the original `$data` (before  preg_replace), and supports all Unicode not just a subset.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use stripcslashes!